# An integral which when evaluated leads to a better bound on a familiar constant. What is the bound and the constant?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, approximation, pi

An integral which when evaluated leads to a better bound on a familiar constant. What is the bound and the constant?

$$ \frac{1}{3164}\int_0^1 \frac{x^8(1-x)^8\left(25 + 816x^2\right)}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x^8%281-x%29^8%2825%2B816x^2%29%2F%281%2Bx^2%29+from+0+to+1) evaluates the integral (without the leading factor) as $9940-3164\pi\approx 0.000844042$, so we get $0 \lt \frac {9940}{3146}-\pi \lt 2.69\cdot 10^{-7}$

Answer (score 2):

For completion's sake (even though it's an old question) here's a solution verifying Wolfram's result posted in the comments.

Denoting $x^8(1-x)^8\left(25 + 816x^2\right)$ as $f(x)$ we get
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \left(25x^8 + 816x^{10}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{8}\binom{8}{k} (-x)^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{8}25\binom{8}{k} (-1)^k x^{k+8} +\sum_{k=0}^{8}816\binom{8}{k} (-1)^k x^{k+10}\\
&= \sum_{n=8}^{16}25\binom{8}{n-8} (-1)^{n} x^{n} +\sum_{n=10}^{18}816\binom{8}{n-10} (-1)^n x^{n}\\
&= \sum_{n=8}^{9}25\binom{8}{n-8} (-1)^{n} x^{n} + \sum_{n=10}^{16}\left[25\binom{8}{n-8}+816\binom{8}{n-10} \right](-1)^{n} x^{n} +\sum_{n=17}^{18}816\binom{8}{n-10} (-1)^n x^{n}\\
 &=816 x^{18} - 6528 x^{17} + 22873 x^{16} - 45896 x^{15} + 57820 x^{14} - 47096 x^{13} + 24598 x^{12} - 7928 x^{11} + 1516 x^{10} - 200 x^{9} + 25 x^{8}
\end{align*}
remembering that $\binom{a}{b} = \frac{a!}{b! (a-b)!}$. Applying [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division) to simplify $\frac{x^8(1-x)^8\left(25 + 816x^2\right)}{x^2+1}$ gives:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
    \begin{array}{rr} \\ &-1 \\ 0& \\ \\ \end{array}
    &
    \begin{array}{|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr|rr} 
x^{16} &x^{15} &x^{14} &x^{13} &x^{12} &x^{11} &x^{10} &x^9 &x^8 &x^7 &x^6 &x^5 &x^4 &x^3 &x^2 &x^1 &x^0  \\
\hline
        816 & - 6528 &  22873 & -45896 & 57820 & -47096 & 24598 & -7928 & 1516 & -200 & 25 & 0  & 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
          &     &  -816 & 6528&-22057 &39368&-35763 & 7728 & 11165 &200 &- 12681 & 0 & 12656 & 0 & -12656 &0& 12656&0&-12656\\
          &  0 & 0 &  0 & 0&  0& 0 &0&0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 &0&0&0\\
        \hline 
        816 &  -6528&  22057& -39368 &35763&-7728 &-11165 & -200 & 12681 & 0 &-12656 & 0 & 12656 &0 &-12656&0 & 12656 & 0 & -12656\\    
    \end{array}
\end{array}
$$
And thus
$$
\frac{x^8(1-x)^8\left(25 + 816x^2\right)}{x^2+1} = 816 x^{16} - 6528 x^{15} + 22057 x^{14} - 39368 x^{13} + 35763 x^{12} - 7728 x^{11} - 11165 x^{10} - 200 x^9 + 12681 x^8 - 12656 x^6 + 12656 x^4 - 12656 x^2 + 12656- \frac{12656}{x^2 + 1} 
$$
So integrating term by term evaluates the integral $I =\int_0^1 \frac{x^8(1-x)^8(25 + 816x^2)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x$ as:
\begin{align*}
I &=\frac{816}{17}  - \frac{6528}{16} + \frac{22057}{15}  - \frac{39368}{14}  + \frac{35763}{13}  - \frac{7728}{12}  - \frac{11165}{11} - \frac{200}{10}  + \frac{12681}{9}  - \frac{12656}{7} + \frac{12656}{5} - \frac{12656}{3} + 12656- 12656\,\underbrace{\text{arctan}(1)}_{\color{blue}{\pi/4}}\\
& = 48 -408+\frac{22057}{15}-2812+2751-644-1015-20+1409-1808+ \frac{12656}{5}\left(\color{purple}{\frac33} \right)-\frac{12656}{3}\left(\color{purple}{\frac55} \right) + 12656 -3164 \pi\\
& = 10157+\frac{22057}{15}+\frac{37968}{15} -\frac{63280}{15} -3164 \pi\\
& = 10157 -\frac{3255}{15}  -3164 \pi\\
& =10157 -217 -3164 \pi\\
& = 9940 - 3164 \pi
\end{align*}
and dividing this result by $3164$ allows us to conclude that
$$
\boxed{\frac{1}{3164}\int_0^1 \frac{x^8(1-x)^8(25 + 816x^2)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x =\frac{355}{113} - \pi}
$$
since $\frac{9940}{3146} = \frac{355}{113}$.

Finally, since the integrand $\frac{x^8(1-x)^8(25 + 816x^2)}{1+x^2}$ is continuous and strictly positive on $(0,1)$ we can conclude that the [integral is also positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1209252/695196) on said interval. In other words, this means $I>0 \implies \frac{1}{3164}I>0 \implies \frac{355}{113} - \pi>0 \implies\boxed{ \frac{355}{113} > \pi}$. This is a very nice result, as implied by the question, since $\frac{355}{113}$ is known to be one of the [best rational approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Continued_fraction_expansion_of_%CF%80_and_its_convergents) to $\pi$.

Comment: Both your links are to the same page.

Comment: @TonyK Beat me to it! I was just editing those mistakes as you typed your comment. Thank you for pointing it out!