# Prove $\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)dx}>0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f\ge0$ be integrable on $[a,b]$. Let $f$ be continuous on $x_0\in (a,b)$ and let $f(x_0)>0$.

Prove $$\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)dx}>0$$

It is easy to see it, graphically, because $$f\ge 0 \Rightarrow\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)dx}\ge0$$

and if $f>0$ somewhere between $a$ and $b$, then the zone of $F$ between those point is "real" (positive) and $\ne 0$.

My problem is, how do I show it **formally**?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Stated as it is, it's not true. You may want to clarify the hypothesis

Comment: What is not true? 
That is why I am in need of assistance.

Comment: Question for clarification: is this a good rephrasing of your question: "if $f$ is a nonnegative continuous function on $[a,b]$ and there exists $x_0 \in (a,b)$ such that $f(x_0) >0$, then is it true that $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx > 0$"?

Comment: @MartinR, doesn't continuity ensure that there is more than one positive point?

Comment: Oops, I had overlooked the continuity! Sorry !!! – Comment deleted.

Comment: @JasonKnapp It is, except it is integrable, originally, not continuous...

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel Do you know that if $\;f\;$ is continuous on $\;[a,b]\;$ and positive there, then $\;\int_a^b f(x)\,dx >0\;$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea:

We're given $\;f\;$ is continuous and non-negative on $\;(a,b)\;$ and such that for some $\;x_0\in (a,b)\;,\;\;f(x_0)>0\;$ .

From continuity we get that there exists $\;\epsilon>0\;$ s.t. $\;f(x)>0\;\;\;\forall\;x\in (x_0-\epsilon\,,\,\,x_0+\epsilon)\;$ .

Since we're given $\;f\;$ is integrable and non-negative in $\;[a,b]\;$ , we then get

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\ge\int_{x_0-\epsilon}^{x_0+\epsilon}f(x)\,dx>0$$

and we're done.

Comment: Saying that $\int_{x_0-\epsilon}^{x_0+\epsilon} f(x)\,dx > 0$ since $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ essentially relies on what the OP is asking to prove, no?

Comment: No, not really, and that's why I asked her whether she already knew that. Now, if she answers and says sho doesn't then it is pretty easy to show this.

Comment: How do you show this without (essentially) first proving the claim in the original post?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Directly: if $\;f(x)>0\;\;\;\forall\,x\in[a,b]\;$ and continuous there, then it is integrable and we can take *any* partitions of the interval we like as far as they fulfill the conditions for the integral. Now, Weierstrass  Boundness Theorem tells us $\;f\;$ is bounded below and it attains its minimum there, say $$m=\min_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)=f(w)>0$$ Thus, for any Riemann sum (i.e., for any valid partition of the interval) we get $$\sum_{i=1}^n f(c_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})\ge f(w)\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1})=f(w)(b-a)>0$$

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Marvelous. 
2. I am a male. 
3. I did not know, however, that if $f>0$ on $I$ then $\int f>0$. 
I shall try to understand your explanation.

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel (1) Thank you, (2) sorry: the only Meitar I ever met was a girl, (3) any doubt ask.

Comment: The only wondering left is; how can I explain that $\int_{a}^{b}f$ is greater than an integral from $x$ to $y$ where $x,y$ are respectively smaller than $a,b$? I went through the definition, claims, and theorems, and didn't find something that can help me. Is a thorough proof required?

Comment: That is because the non-negativity. I see.
So all the addends are non-negative. Makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Let $m = \frac{f(x_0)}{2}$. There exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) > m$ for all $x \in [x_0 - \delta, x_0 +\delta]$. Take any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ that contains the points $x_0 - \delta$ and $x_0 +\delta$, then we have

$$L(f:P) > 2m\delta \tag {*}$$

Thus as $f$ is integrable

$$\int_a^bf(x) \,dx \geq L(f:P) > 2m\delta$$

**Edit:**
$(*)$

> Notice that for some $s \in \{0,1,\ldots, n\}$ we have that $$m_s = \inf _{f \in [x_0 -\delta, x_0 + \delta ]} f \geq m > 0$$Now if you split 
>  $$L(f;P) = \sum_{i=1}^{s-1} \underbrace{m_i}_{\geq 0}\underbrace{\Delta_{i-1}}_{>0} + \underbrace{m_s}_{\geq m}\underbrace{\Delta_{s-1}}_{\geq 2m\delta} + \sum_{i=s+1}^{n} \underbrace{m_i}_{\geq 0}\underbrace{\Delta_{i-1}}_{>0} \geq m(x_0 - \delta , x_0 + \delta) > 2m\delta $$

Comment: You seem to be assuming $\;x_0\;$ is a minimal point of $\;\frac{f(x)}2\;$ . Why?

Comment: I don't really understand what $L(f:P).

Comment: @AaronMaroja I just can't understand that. What if $\;m:=f(x_0)\;$ is *the maximum* of $\;f\;$ on $\;[a,b]\;$ ? Or even better: what if $\;f(x_0)\;$ is not a local extreme point of $\;f\;$ at all?!

Comment: Make sure you have tried something first, before looking the answer.

Comment: @AaronMaroja You still continue to assume $\;m=f(x_0)\;$ is some kind of minimal point of $\;f\;$ somewhere. Do you care to explain this?

Comment: @Timbuc Okay, let's get back to real analysis 101. If we take $\epsilon = \frac{f(x_0)}{2} > 0$ then there surely exists $\delta > 0$ (due to the continuity of $f$ at $x_0$) such that $$x \in (x_0 -\delta, x_0 + \delta) \implies f(x) > f(x_0) -\frac{f(x_0)}{2} = \frac{f(x_0)}{2}$$

Are you pleased now? Can I have my points back?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel It's the [lower sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LowerSum.html).

Comment: @AaronMaroja So sorry for your points, but I almost never downvote  (not even if the answer has some big mistake) , and neither did this time. I think downloading is mostly for losers, in particular if they do it without explaining. And thanks for the invitation to analysis 101, though it took you quite some time to address my question.

Comment: @Timbuc You know, it's really important for the student to think over a problem for quite some time, that's why I just gave a **hint**, and that's precisely the reason I didn't address  to your question. It makes you mature faster, and you totally took this learning time from Meitar. Anyways, it's cool.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Oh, don't worry about Meitar: she seems to be out of the site for quite some time now. And I don't think your hint would have been hurt if you had answered my question before

Comment: @Timbuc I just don't agree. Using the hypothesis is essential on that part. You wouldn't have a $\delta$ to work with in the first place, and for some bad sketching of yours you just couldn't see that and were asking something completely out of question.  All I'm asking is: be patient next time and don't spoil all the fun.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Fair request from you, Aaron. But maybe next time you will also tell that to whomever asks you something. Had you written that you're waiting some time to  pass for the OP to think on this or that and I would have waited. Thank you.

Comment: @Timbuc No problem, note taken. Even though I'm pretty sure the word **hint** gives you that.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the point $x_0$. Positivity and continuity imply that $f(x) > 0$ for a *lot* of points near $x_0$. Fix some $0 < \varepsilon < f(x_0)$. By the definition of continuity, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $$x \in [a, b]\, \text{ and }\,0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon.$$
Of course, $x = x_0$ also implies $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$, and we can shrink $\delta$ (if necessary) to get the following stronger statement: $$x \in [x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta] \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon.$$
Now, $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$ implies $f(x) > f(x_0) - \varepsilon$, and that lower bound is *positive* by choice of $\varepsilon$. This means that under the curve $y = f(x)$ we have a little solid rectangle with base $[x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta]$ reaching up to the line $y = f(x_0) - \varepsilon$. So, $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ is at least the area of this rectangle, namely $2\delta(f(x_0)-\varepsilon)$, and this is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Bound the integral below by the usual lower-sum approximation, choosing the left endpoint of each interval for the height. Then you will have a non-negative lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

All the proofs I have seen use the fact that if $f$ is continuous and $f(x_0) > 0$, then $f$ is positive on a small interval. Here is a proof that does not use such an argument.

By contrapositive, let's suppose that $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, non-negative, and satisfies $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(t) dt = 0$.

Let $F$ denote a primitive function of $F$ on $[a,b]$ (which exists because $f$ is continuous). Then $0=\displaystyle\int_a^b f(t) dt = F(b)-F(a)$, so $F(a)=F(b)$. But $F'=f \geq 0$, so $F$ is increasing.

This implies directly that $F$ is constant, hence $f=0$.